# Spring Cloud Gateway throws 500 error when remote server close connection

Tags: spring, spring-boot, netty, spring-cloud

I implemented custom GatewayFilterFactory to implement custom security. I am observing intermittent issue which occurs when connection abruptly closed between gateway and remote server.

Spring cloud gateway swallow exception and throwing 500 internal server error to the client.

Complete stacktrace-

```
java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
              at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
              at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
              at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
              at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
              at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380) ~[na:1.8.0_201]
              at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1132) ~[netty-buffer-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:347) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:148) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:677) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:612) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:529) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:491) ~[netty-transport-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:905) ~[netty-common-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_201]

2019-11-21 23:14:26.923 DEBUG [GatewayRoutingService,723236e66f776061,723236e66f776061,false] 18400 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] o.s.c.g.h.RoutePredicateHandlerMapping   : Route matched: grs_rapid_mercht_search_api_node


avax.net.ssl.SSLException: handshake timed out
              at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.handshake(...)(Unknown Source) ~[netty-handler-4.1.33.Final.jar:4.1.33.Final]
```

Sample Implementation-

```
public class MyFilterFactory implements GatewayFilterFactory<JwtService.JwtConfig> {
private static  final  Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(JwtFilterFactory.class);
public static final String RETRY_ITERATION_KEY = "retry_iteration";

@Override
public GatewayFilter apply(JwtService.JwtConfig config) {

        Predicate<RepeatContext<ServerWebExchange>> repeatPredicate = context -> {
            ServerWebExchange exchange = context.applicationContext();
            if (exceedsMaxIterations(exchange, config)) {
                return false;
            }

            HttpStatus statusCode = exchange.getResponse().getStatusCode();
            return config.getUnAuthStatusCode().equals(statusCode)|| statusCode.is5xxServerError();
        };

    Repeat<ServerWebExchange>  statusCodeRepeat = Repeat.onlyIf(repeatPredicate)
                .doOnRepeat(context -> reset(context.applicationContext()));

    return (exchange, chain) -> {

        Publisher<Void> publisher = chain.filter(exchange.mutate().request(
                exchange.getRequest().mutate().
                        //Populate Request header
                                header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION,jwtTokenFormatted)
                        .build()).build())
                .doOnSuccessOrError((aVoid, throwable) -> {
                    int iteration = exchange
                            .getAttributeOrDefault(RETRY_ITERATION_KEY, -1);
                    int newIteration = iteration + 1;

                    exchange.getAttributes().put(RETRY_ITERATION_KEY, newIteration);
                });

        if (statusCodeRepeat != null) {
            publisher = ((Mono<Void>) publisher)
                    .repeatWhen(statusCodeRepeat.withApplicationContext(exchange));
        }

        return Mono.fromDirect(publisher);
    };

}

public boolean exceedsMaxIterations(ServerWebExchange exchange,
                                    JwtService.JwtConfig retryConfig) {
    Integer iteration = exchange.getAttribute(RETRY_ITERATION_KEY);
    // TODO: deal with null iteration
    boolean exceeds = iteration != null && iteration >= retryConfig.getRetries();
    LOGGER.trace("exceedsMaxIterations %b, iteration %d, configured retries %d", exceeds,
            iteration, retryConfig.getRetries());
    return exceeds;
}


public void reset(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    LOGGER.debug("Inside reset method :{} ",exchange.getRequest().getHeaders());
    Set<String> addedHeaders = exchange.getAttributeOrDefault(
            CLIENT_RESPONSE_HEADER_NAMES, Collections.emptySet());
    addedHeaders
            .forEach(header -> exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().remove(header));
    exchange.getAttributes().remove(GATEWAY_ALREADY_ROUTED_ATTR);

}
}
```

Any suggestions for below queries-

- How to make sure netty forward connection/handshake error to client instead of throwing 500 internal server error?
- How to reestablish the closed connection?

Comment: did you got solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `spring.cloud.gateway.loadbalancer.use404=true` would be useful here.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a retry in your config? That would solve your second issue.
Not sure where the doc lies, but you can check `org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.factory.RetryGatewayFilterFactory` implementation, the sample config would be like below

```yaml
spring.cloud.gateway:
  default-filters:
    - name: Retry
      args:
        retries: 3
        statuses:
          - BAD_GATEWAY
          - SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE
          - GATEWAY_TIMEOUT
        methods:
        - GET
        - POST
        - PUT
        exceptions:
          - java.io.IOException
          - org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.NotFoundException
          - org.springframework.cloud.gateway.support.TimeoutException
        backoff:
          firstBackoff: 500ms
          maxBackoff: 2s
          factor: 2
          basedOnPreviousValue: true
```